# interval rxjs not clearing timer

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Input property as setter:

```
   @Input() set moduleData(value: any) {
    this._moduleData = value;
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
    this.startAttempt();
  } 



  startAttempt() {
    if (!this.isExamStarted()) {
      console.log("exam is not started");
      interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res) => {
        if (
          this.canStartAssessment(this.moduleData.module_progress.start_time)
        ) {
          console.log("exam can be started now");
          this.getTimeRemainingInExam();
        } else {
          this.getTimer(
            this.moduleData.module_progress.start_time,
            false
          );
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.getTimeRemainingInExam();
    }
  }


ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("componenet destroyef");
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

By using the takeUntil operator , im trying to stop the timer. I can see that the timer still runs even after the component is destroyed. Also when the input property changes i can see that in 1 sec it is getting called twice . For ex , the logs are printed twice , as many as the input  of previous values. How to clear all the intervals when the input property changes before starting interval again?

Comment: Your `interval`'s `takeUntil(destroy$)` is never going to complete. `destory$` has already completed before the interval begins. Once a stream completes or errors, it is done and will never emit another value again. Calling `.next()` on a completed subject has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.subscription` has to be killed. You could add this snippet

```
interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res) => {
  [...]
});
```

into a subscriptions array and unsubscribe from it in the ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook.

```
subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

startAttempt() {
  [...]
  this.subscriptions.push(
    interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res) => {
      [...]
    })
  )
  [...]
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to `complete` the multicast observable `destroy$`.

1. Once complete, they aren't started again.
2. If the observable is used only for the `takeUntil`, the `complete` is redundant. Just the `next` is enough. Refer [here](https://twitter.com/michael_hladky/status/1193641068635590656?lang=en).

Try the following

```js
@Input() set moduleData(value: any) {
  this._moduleData = value;
  this.destroy$.next(); // <-- `complete()` not required
  this.startAttempt();
}

...
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  console.log("component destroyed");
  this.destroy$.next(); // <-- `complete()` not required
}
```

Comment: thanks. I understand its not required, but doesn't solve the problem im facing.

Comment: @MohitHarshan This should fix your problem. You're problem is that you call `this.destroy$.complete()` in `set moduleData`. So you complete `destroy$` before `startAttempt` is called and `destroy$` won't be able to send any notifications to `takeUntil` from then on.